# while doing data driver testing through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am facing a problem while doing data driven testing through excel using selenium webdriver. i am getting a error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException' present i am using poi jar files

this is the code

```
InputStream file=new FileInputStream("D:\\Logins.xlsx");
        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        Sheet s=wb.getSheetAt(1);
        String uname=s.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String pwd=s.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        wd.findElement(By.id("LoginID")).sendKeys(uname);
        wd.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(pwd);
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Please check below :                                                                                                     http://www.ontestautomation.com/data-driven-testing-in-selenium-webdriver-using-excel/

Also make sure you have imported all required POI Jars.

Comment: To work with XLSX , you will need to user XLSX classes like below: http://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html